# Product of a distribution and a function

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am working on a problem which contains the following:

> Suppose that $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfies $xu = 0$.

Where $\mathcal{D}'$ is the space of distributions. Now, I am not completely sure what this should mean. $x$ is a function, which is not even compactly supported, whereas $u$ is a distribution. Could someone explain what I am supposed to think of this?

Comment: For a *smooth* function $f$ and a distribution $u$, the product is defined as $fu(\varphi)=u(f\varphi)$ for test functions $\varphi$. Note that $f\varphi$ is smooth with support contained in that of $\varphi$.

Comment: Fair enough, I missed that. Thanks

Comment: I think you can post that as an answer